# Transferring arrays from Matlab Application Server to F#

Tags: .net, matlab, f#

I have a problem with transferring multidimensional arrays from a Matlab Application server to an F# scripting-session.

```
#I @"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin\win64";;
#r @"MLApp.dll";;
let matlab=new MLApp.MLAppClass();;
matlab.Execute("a=[1 2 3 4 5;6 7 8 9 10]");;
let b =matlab.GetVariable("a","base");;
let arr = b :?> float[]
```

After applying the downcast the array has type array2D, float[,]. But is the array displayed like this:

```
arr;;
val it : float [,] = [[1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
                      [4.0; 5.0; 6.0]]
```

For a rectangular array, I am used to get something like this

```
arr;;
                    = [|[|1.0; 2.0; 3.0|]
                      [|4.0; 5.0; 6.0|]|]
```

Where is the difference between these types? And why can't I apply array slicing to arr of type float[,]?

Answer (score 2):

The type `float[,]` represents two-dimensional array. You can work with it using functions from the `Array2D` module and you can access elements by specifying the two indices (such as `arr.[0, 0]`). The array has to be regular (rectangle), so you can also use slicing, because all values in the rectangle are defined.

```
> let arr2d = array2D [ [1 .. 3]; [4 .. 6] ];;
val arr2d : int [,] = [[1; 2; 3]
                       [4; 5; 6]]

> arr2d.[1,1];;
val it : int = 5
```

The type `float[][]` which you got in the second case is a 1-dimensional array containing 1-dimensional arrays of `float`. To access an element, you first need to specify the index of the first array and then pick an element in the returned array:

```
> let arrOfArr = [| [| 1 .. 3 |]; [| 0 |] |];;
val arrOfArr : int [] [] = [|[|1; 2; 3|]; [|0|]|]

> arrOfArr.[0].[1];;
val it : int = 2
```

As this example shows, the type `float[][]` does not have to represent rectangular array, because the individual arrays may have different length (i.e. 3 and 1 in the above example). This is a reason why you cannot use slicing to access its elements.

If you have array of type `float[][]`, then you can convert it to `float[,]` using `array2D` function. The function will fail if the array is not rectangular.

Comment: Tomas, what an honour! If I understand it correctly, the array of array type is also called "Jagged Array"? Concerning the slicing, if I try to do something like `arr.[0,0..2]`, I get the error message: `This expression was expected to have type
    'a []    
but here has type
    float [,]`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Arrays of arrays are also called "jagged arrays". Regarding the slicing, you always need to specify slices for both of the indices (and the result will be a 2D array, even if you actually select just one element in one of the dimensions). For example: `arr.[0..0,0..2]`